# share a text with sms

Tags: android

how can i share a text from my application with sms ?

i want to for example user touch a button and a costum text will be sent to default messaging application and it will ask for number

this is the menu code  :

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        return true;
        case R.id.menu_share:
return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start launch the sms activity all you need is this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   

sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
```

This will open a chooser where people can choose the number/contact to send message to

```
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+ phoneNumber));
```

This will send message to predefined number.

You can add extras to populate your own message and such like this

```
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", x);
```

Then start your intent:

```
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: i want to user / messaging application chose the number , i just wanna send body

Comment: Then don't add + phoneNumber. Only `sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));` , answer updated. Dont forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: causes FC , shuld i add permission or sth ?

Comment: of course      `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>` . You should really do some research on your own before asking every step you take. There is a lot of documentation on the web. I found at least 10 answers and tutorials similar to this.

Comment: fc... , can u gimme some links ?